# SQL query to find the average number of employees per company in a database

Tags: sql, oracle, average

The goal of this query is to find the average number of employees per company in my database. Here is what I currently have for my query, along with my result:

```
create view Totals as
((select distinct count(company_name) as TotalCompanies, company_name
  from company
  group by company_name)
 union
(select distinct count(Lastname) as TotalEmps, company_name
   from Works
   group by company_name));


select avg(TotalCompanies) from Totals;

--RESULT:
AVG(TOTALCOMPANIES)
2.777777777778
```

While I did get a result (so I do not believe there are any syntax errors), based on the actual data I've inputted into my tables, I do not believe this value is correct.

Is what I'm doing in my view creation even getting me to an appropriate point where I can just call the average function of the TotalCompanies field of that view? My intent was to count all the employees per company name in the view, and then average those values...

For an FYI, I am using SQL for Oracle 11g R2 and here is my initial schema I'm creating queries for:

```
create table Employee(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    gender      char(1),
    street      varchar(10),
    city        varchar(10),
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial));

create table company(
    company_name    varchar(20),
    city    varchar(10),
    primary key(company_name));

create table Works(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    company_name    varchar(20),
    salary      numeric(8,2),
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, company_name),
    foreign key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial) references Employee,
    foreign key(company_name) references company);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would like also to note that your schema leaves a room for improvement.  You need to introduce `int` Primary and Foreign keys. Then you will not to have to repeat the full employee name and company name in `Works`.  Since there could be people and companies with exactly the same names, your keys are not guaranteed to be **unique**.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside issues about the schema, I believe the following will work:

```
Select
    Avg(employeeCount)
From (
    Select
        company_name,
        count(coalesce(w.LastName, w.FirstName, w.MidInitial)) employeeCount
    From
        company c
            left outer join
        works w
            on c.company_name = w.company_name
    Group By
       company_name
) x
```

It's slightly tricky to deal with companies with 0 employees, and people with null as one of their names (I'm not sure if Oracle actually allows this in primary key columns, but the definition seems to imply it)

Comment: It shouldn't be tricky to deal with companies with 0 employees; it's certainly possible in real life, it'll work with the average and the count you have here will give you 0 for those companies. Oracle does not allow NULL columns in a PK though...

Comment: @Ben by slightly tricky, I meant trickier than pretending it can't happen and just using the `works` table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view to store the total number of employees working in each employee.

```
create view Totals as
    (select count(*) as No_of_employees,company_name from Employee,Works
     where Employee.Lastname = Works.Lastname and
         Employee.FirstName = Works.FirstName and
         Employee.MidInitial = Works.MidInitial
     group by Works.company_name);
```

Now write a query to find the average number of employees working in each company:

```
select avg(No_of_employees) from Totals;
```

This should give you the correct answer. I tried this using MySQL. Pardon me for any typos.